# Why are my sensors not working (the reaction time is so slow)?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, potentiometer, photoresistor

[image]

```
//testing the light sensor;
int sensor=A0; // setting as input is by default;
int sensorval;
int pin=13;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensor,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  sensorval=analogRead(sensor);
  Serial.println(sensorval);
  if(sensorval>900)
    digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
  else  digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

I am using a photocell, a temperature sensor and a potentiometer with an Arduino Uno and it always gives me `1023 0 1023 0 1023 0 1023 ......`. All my wires are connected properly and I tried all this stuff online and they are working correctly.

Comment: [Link](https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/944641-the-unnamed-circuit/edit)

Comment: For future reference, you don't need to start a new question if you want to add information. You can edit your existing questions. On this occasion though, I've deleted your previous one since it's no longer needed.

Comment: Ok thank you actually it is my first time ::D @PeterR.Bloomfield

Comment: what about this issue now @PeterR.Bloomfield

Comment: Perhaps you can add a Fritzing layout of your project. It seems like there's an issue with your pot.

Comment: It's "slow" because you have a 1 second (1000 mS) delay in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with a different trimmer?

I dont seem to be able to find any issue with your code or your schematic, so can you please cross verify that the trimmer is not spoilt.

Can you also check if, when A0 is left floating (nothing connected) it give a random value.

Comment: Yes ! when A0 is floating it gives random values @evolutionizer

Comment: Have you tried with a new trimmer?

Comment: No ,but I've tried another analog device like a photocell or a temp. sensor and seems to have the same random values @evolitionizer

Comment: Can you confirm that your connection is similar to this http://bildr.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/arduino-LDR-photoresistor1.png

Comment: By this way it is working but too slow .in light ,it reads 1023 then slowing down until reaches 0 and vice versa  @evolitionizer

Comment: @nohierhassan You might also like to attach a photograph of your setup so we can double-check your wiring.

Comment: [link](https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/945011-the-unnamed-circuit/edit) this is the wiring @Majenko

Comment: @nohierhassan That's not a photo, that's a wiring diagram. We need a real photo of your real wiring so we can make sure you haven't had a brainfart while wiring it up (it happens to the best of us).

Comment: @nohierhassan What do you mean by "By this way it is working but too slow .in light ,it reads 1023 then slowing down until reaches 0 and vice versa "

From this it sounds like it seems to be doing exactly what it is supposed to do. What exactly do you mean by it is too slow? The reaction time?

Comment: Yes, the reaction time . i saw videos the sensor works immediately (once the light turns off it reads 1023 ). @evolutionizer

Comment: @nohier can you please Post a picture of your setup, actual picture and if possible a video of the working

Comment: @evolutionizer check the photo

Comment: @nohier please connect a Jumper wire between the left and right most power rails. Please have a look at this image for a typical breadboard internal connection img.webme.com/pic/w/whitelinetracer/breadboard1.gif

Comment: Also if possible please upload a higher resolution picture

Answer (score 1):

you should internalize value of sensorval equal to zero.
You do not require set analog pin.
you want get data quickly then reduce delay time because 1 second quite high.So, make it **500** mili second.